# MySQL MAX Count by day

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider TABLE with columns Date and IP. I'm trying to get the max count of IP by day.

FYI I am using LEFT(date, LOCATE(',', date, LOCATE(',', date) +1) -1) to parse out the hour time from the strings since it's for some reason type string.

```
SELECT dates, MAX(countIP) as max 
FROM (
    SELECT LEFT(date, LOCATE(',', date, LOCATE(',', date) +1) -1) as dates, 
            COUNT(ip) as countIP
    FROM `apilogs`
    GROUP BY dates) as testing
GROUP BY dates;
```

Please help point me in the right direction

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a few rows of sample data and your desired result from that data. There's no way we could begin to help you without that.

Comment: Doing a grouping on a runtime compute value is really expensive. If you expect that you will do that on a huge amount of rows you then should create a dedicate column with an index.

Comment: It looks like your `LEFT` and `LOCATE` code is duplicating what `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` does. It will be easier to understand if you use that function.

Comment: You could also use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse it as a date.

Comment: What's wrong with the query as it is, other than possible performance issues?

Comment: What are you trying to get the max of? You just have one count per day, so it's the same as the max count per day. Are you trying to get the IP with the max count each day? In that case the subquery needs to group by IP and date.